# How to show template in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I need load template html in page by click. I tried to do:

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.selectDialog = function (id, event){ 
   $scope.template = '/template/chat/active_dialog.html';
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-include="template"></div> Does not work
<div ng-include="{{template}}"></div>
<div>{{template}}</div>
```

Comment: What does your console tell you?

Comment: There are not errors. Instead template I get string(path) in HTML

Comment: from angularJS docs  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: I tried: `<div ng-include=" '{{template}}' "></div>` does not work too

Answer (score 0):

Two ways,

this:

```
$scope.selectDialog = function (id, event)
{ 
   $scope.template = [ 
      { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
      { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'} 
   ];
       $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
};
```

And in your page

```
<div ng-include="template.url"></div>
```

or you can use  [templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

```
  $scope.selectDialog = function (id, event){ 
       $scope.template = $templateCache.get('/template/chat/active_dialog.html');
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, but at HTML template use simply `{{template}}`?

Comment: must be ng-include="template"

Comment: look my edit answer...  and look this docs for $templatecache https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: Thanks, but here tells that run outside controller like as: `myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});`

Comment: @sahe look this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude and go to the plkr

Comment: How to connect `$templateCache` in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, it's hard to tell what you did wrong. But I created a working version code in Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ll1x35zhDG72Mc5qYD04?p=preview

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <button ng-click="selectDialog()">Select Dialog</button>

    <div ng-include="template"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('includeExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.template = '';
  $scope.selectDialog = function (id, event){ 
     $scope.template = 'active_dialog.html';
     console.log($scope.template);
  }; 
}]);
```

Comment: But if load html from outside resourse?

Comment: What do you mean load html from outside resource? Can you post a Plunker sample of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` is very tricky at first. It is created to ease the loading of external resources. So:

- `ng-include="template"` will try to load `/template` resource on the
  server.
- `ng-include="template.url"` will try to load `/template.url` resource
  on the server.
- `ng-include="templates/main.html"` will load `/templates/main.html`
  resource on the server.

The only way to reference a URL inside a variable (or expression in angular language) is to wrap the expression in **[single quotes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)**. With that said, your main template should be like this:

```
<div ng-include="'template'"></div> Not single quotes inside double ones.
```

Comment: If I need load template from root directory server I need specify `/template/chat/active_dialog.html` or full path with http?

Comment: I tried: `$scope.template = 'http://wgoi.tk/template/chat/active_dialog.html'` `<div ng-include="'template'"></div>` it did not load html at page

Comment: Is `http://wgoi.tk` the same server the angular script in served from? If it is not, then you may have a CORS issue here. Protocol (`http`) and server is not required. It is automatically filled by the browser when the URL does not start with a protocol.